# How to check for multiple checked boxes in checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checklistbox

This is the schema of the process I want to achieve:

select options from a checkedlistbox ----> compare the indices of checked items with particular set of indices.

In other words I am trying to see if multiple indices/items have been checked.

I am also wondering if this task can be achieved for multiple checkedlistboxes at the same time.

Comment: We need a bit more information, because you said Visual Studio, I'm assuming .Net, but C# or Visual Basic or something else? Are you using WPF or Windows Forms?

Comment: Visual C#, Using Windows Forms

Comment: Use `CheckedItems` or `SelectedItems`.

Comment: Ken, I have used the checkeditems to output to listbox. I am trying to see if there is a way to write a few lines of code to determine if an index or better still multiple indices exist within a set of selections made. Here is what I am thinking:   does( x,y,z) exist in checkeditems or selected items

Comment: @Sam, to complement @Ken comment, maybe you need to play with `CheckedListBox.CheckedIndices` instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is not an automatic method giving you the info you want. But you can roll you own, of course. For example, an extension method can be created in order to check whether the indices you provide to it are present or not.

```
    static class CheckedListBoxExtension {
        public static bool ContainsSet(this WinForms.CheckedListBox cbl, ICollection<int> values)
        {
            var valueSet = new HashSet<int>( values );

            foreach(int index in cbl.CheckedIndices) {
                if ( valueSet.Contains( index ) ) {
                    valueSet.Remove( index );

                }
            }

            return valueSet.Count == 0;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
if ( this.checkBoxes.ContainsSet( new int[]{ 2, 4 } ) ) {
            // Your code here...
}
```

A complete example follows:

```
class Window: WinForms.Form {
    public Window()
    {
        this.Build();
        this.MinimumSize = new Drawing.Size( 320, 200 );
    }

    void Build()
    {
        this.status = new WinForms.TextBox { Dock = WinForms.DockStyle.Bottom };
        this.checkBoxes = new WinForms.CheckedListBox {
            Dock = WinForms.DockStyle.Fill 
        };

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
            this.checkBoxes.Items.Add(
                char.ToString( (char) ( 'a' + i ) ),
                false
            );
        }

        this.checkBoxes.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) => this.UpdateCheckedList();
        this.Controls.Add( this.checkBoxes );
        this.Controls.Add( this.status );
    }

    void UpdateCheckedList()
    {
        string strStatus = "";

        if ( this.checkBoxes.ContainsSet( new int[]{ 2, 4 } ) ) {
            strStatus += "YES";
        }

        this.status.Text = strStatus;
    }

    WinForms.CheckedListBox checkBoxes;
    WinForms.TextBox status;
}

static class CheckedListBoxExtension {
    public static bool ContainsSet(this WinForms.CheckedListBox cbl, ICollection<int> values)
    {
        var valueSet = new HashSet<int>( values );

        foreach(int index in cbl.CheckedIndices) {
            if ( valueSet.Contains( index ) ) {
                valueSet.Remove( index );

            }
        }

        return valueSet.Count == 0;
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

(PS. the Visual Basic.NET follows)

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Class Window
    Inherits WinForms.Form

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Build()
        Me.MinimumSize = New Drawing.Size(320, 200)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Build()
        Me.status = New WinForms.TextBox With {
            .Dock = WinForms.DockStyle.Bottom
        }
        Me.checkBoxes = New WinForms.CheckedListBox With {
            .Dock = WinForms.DockStyle.Fill
        }

        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            Me.checkBoxes.Items.Add(Char.ToString(ChrW(("a"c + i))), False)
        Next

        Me.checkBoxes.SelectedIndexChanged += Function(sender, e) Me.UpdateCheckedList()
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.checkBoxes)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.status)
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateCheckedList()
        Dim strStatus As String = ""

        If Me.checkBoxes.ContainsSet(New Integer() {2, 4}) Then
            strStatus += "YES"
        End If

        Me.status.Text = strStatus
    End Sub

    Private checkBoxes As WinForms.CheckedListBox
    Private status As WinForms.TextBox
End Class

Module CheckedListBoxExtension
    <Extension()>
    Function ContainsSet(ByVal cbl As WinForms.CheckedListBox, ByVal values As ICollection(Of Integer)) As Boolean
        Dim valueSet = New HashSet(Of Integer)(values)

        For Each index As Integer In cbl.CheckedIndices

            If valueSet.Contains(index) Then
                valueSet.Remove(index)
            End If
        Next

        Return valueSet.Count = 0
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks Baltasarq. I will trial it and will get back to you with how well it works in the setting I want to use it.

Comment: Baltasarq, I had a bit of a problem - self made problem you might say. I did not correctly state what language I was using. Its actually Visual Basic not C#. So I tried to use your code but could not successfully carry out.

Comment: Baltasarq, many thanks, finally returned to my coding problem on using checklist. Your code provided the solution I was looking for. However I am trying to understand the extension method - how does it work so as to extend it to other problems. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Can you mark the answer as the accepted one? About extension methods, you can find the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods